# How to connect client to remote server using public IP?

Tags: http, ip, client-server, portforwarding

I have a mobile Android Application which connect to my server application using `sockets`.

I tested the connection when both client and server are connected to the same router (they are in the same private network) and everything works just fine (the client connects to `192.168.1.48` which is a private ip address).

I want my client to connect to my public IP server which can be something like `88.A.B.C` (provided by my local `ISP`)

I tried doing `port forwarding` but I am not sure how to configure it properly or what am I missing.

The client connects to the server having:

`ipAddress: 88.A.B.C
 port: 8888`

I mention that I have an `ASUS router RT-N18U`.

**What I tried**:

1) Connect to: http://192.168.1.1

2) Go to WAN -> Virtual Server / Port Forwarding

3) Add a rule like:[image]

I can not figure out what am I missing or what to do further. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration looks correct. Maybe your ISP is blocking those ports. Try changing the port number and/or use portchecktool to check if it's blocked or not.